# Registered callback does not match with the provided url in wso2 api manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have two server that run in following addresses:

```
https://172.25.129.66:9443/publisher
https://172.25.129.67:9443/publisher
```

I faced with following error in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 :

```
Registered callback does not match with the provided url
```

And also I configured call back url in carbon as folowing :

```
regexp=(https://172.25.129.66:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://172.25.129.66:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout|https://172.25.129.67:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://172.25.129.67:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout)
```

What is the problem that only `https://172.25.129.67:9443/publisher` has call back error?

Answer (score 0):

This error might have occurred due to the mismatch of the API Publisher or API Dev portal access URLs and callback URLs which are configured in API Publisher and API Devportal Service Providers.

Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/#troubleshooting-registered-callback-does-not-match-with-the-provided-url-error to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have read document , but my problem is that https://172.25.129.66:9443/publisher is ok but https://172.25.129.67:9443/publisher has callback error why?